# How to implement automatic view update as soon as there is change in database in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, grails

I am using AngularJs with Grails framework and using Mysql as Database.

I want to implement feature like automatic view update as occur on Facebook.

Till now i am able to send JSON data to angular controller from Grails Controller and populating view.

But how do i implement feature like some one change the database and on real time the views get updated without reloading page.

i cam across

"polling every X milliseconds using $timeout and $http"

will this be efficient for real world application?

Please help me by suggesting some measures or Angular implementations to solve out my problem.

Comment: you could use modern database like firebase for realtime update but if you want to use mysql then polling in x millisecond is best way to synchornize

Comment: You may use the push-based update technology like SocketIO for sending the notification from server to all connecting clients, for every update occurs.

Answer (score 2):

For 'automatic' update of the views, I've used Grails Events Push Plugin, I suggest that you look at it.
http://grails.org/plugin/events-push

It's really easy to send the events to the browser and in the client listen to them and update  the AngularJS scope with the propper information.

**Example**

An angularJS file

```
window.grailsEvents = new grails.Events('http://myAppUrl.com', {enableXDR:true,readResponsesHeaders:false});

/**
 * Module for listening to grails events
 */
angular.module('grailsEvents', []).factory('grailsEvents', function() {
    return window.grailsEvents
});

window.myModule = angular.module('myModule',['grailsEvents'])
   .run(function(){
       grailsEvents.on('myEvent',function(data){
          //Every time an event occurs, this will be executed
          console.log(data);
       });
   });
```

MyEvents.groovy (in grails-app/conf)

```
events = {
    'myEvent' browser:true
}
```

TestController.groovy (an example of a controller that sends an event)

```
class TestController{
    def index(){
       event(topic:'myEvent',data:MyDomain.list())
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please provide me link of a sample application of Event-push along with AngularJs, so that i can understand the working.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've added an small example. If you need more help just tell me

Comment: Thanks Eylen for your response,
can you please host a sample application on Github or at some other repository so that i can understand that as i am unable to use Event Push plugin due to lack of proper documentation.
It will be helpful for everyone and serve as a reference for those who are going to implement Event Push plugin with AngularJs.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to put in GitHub an example, but don't know when because I don't have too much spare time...
I'll tell you when I add it

Comment: I am using Grails 2.2.3 when i installed Event Push plugin and then tried to run my app 
I got below Error:
org.atmosphere#atmosphere-runtime;1.1.0-SNAPSHOT: not found

Comment: Did you add the repo?
mavenRepo "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

Comment: Can you please mail me the application on my mail id shashank.gupta40@gmail.com i need that urgently as i had spend a good amount of time with atmosphere plugin also by no luck

Comment: I'll try, but I'm not sure if I'll be able to send it to you today because I've to create a new one and add the functionality.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42013/discussion-between-shashank-gupta40-and-eylen)

Comment: The example works like a charm. In addition, if you want to listen for events in a controller and update a model, here is how you do:

Comment: How can we achieve this using grails and angular 2 profile?

Answer (score 1):

If you do have to use MySQL, I would suggest a slightly longer route keeping performance in mind. You definitely do not want to keep polling every X seconds. The SocketIO method indicated in the comments is a good way to go. However you need to expand your design a bit.

You will need to implement a "Topic" concept. For example, lets say you have a page called Fruits, that you wish to update automatically when someone posts something about Fruits. So what you would do is to create a "room" (in Socket.IO terminology) called something like /topics/fruits and have anyone who is viewing this page "subscribe" to this room. Next when anyone posts something about fruits, all you would need to do is "push" this new data to the /topics/fruits room and everyone who is on that view will get the update.

Since you are using grails, here is something to get you pointed towards this: http://compiledammit.com/2012/09/05/websockets-and-grails-broadcasting-to-topics/. For the AngularJS part, you can read up at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/ and just implement the Socket.io client part. Just ignore the NodeJS parts on that post.

Answer (score 0):

The example posted by Eylen works like a charm. In addition, if you want to listen for events in a controller and update a model, here is how you do:

```
grailsEvents.on('myEvent', function (data) {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.mymodel = data.someField;
    });        
});
```