# Synchronise database commits in Laravel with AngularJS models/views

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, laravel

We have an web application built in PHP Laravel, which exposes a bunch of schema objects via JSON API calls. We want to tie changes in our schema to AngularJS in such a way that when the database updates, the AngularJS model (and subsequently the view) also updates, in real-time.

In terms of the database, it can be anything, such as mySQL, SQL Server, etc. There's a couple of ways we're thinking about this:

- mySQL commits fire some sort of event at Laravel, which then fires a call to all relevant/listening models/views in AngularJS.
- Before any data is changed (edited/added) - Laravel fires an event to AngularJS. In other words, after any successful DB commit, another "thing" is done to notify.

The second seems the obvious, clean way of doing this - since the database is not involved lower down the stack. Is there any better way of doing this?

This question is related:
[How to implement automatic view update as soon as there is change in database in AngularJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970988/how-to-implement-automatic-view-update-as-soon-as-there-is-change-in-database-in)
but I don't quite understand the concept of a "room" in the answer.

What (if any) is the best way to efficiently tie database commits (pushing) to the AngularJS view (to render changes)? We want to avoid polling a JSON API for changes every second, of course.

Comment: Look into pub/sub with Comet/Long Polling. Web Sockets is nice, but not fully supported yet.

Comment: Would socket.io be suitable in terms of using it with AngularJS and Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

I've also had a similar requirements on one of my projects. We solved it with using node.js and sockjs. Flow is like this:

1. There is a node.js + SockJS server to which all clients connect.
2. When db is updated, laravel issues a command to node.js via http (redis also a posibility)
3. Node.js broadcasts the event to all interested clients (this depends upon your business logic)
4. Either the client reloads the data required or if message is small enough it can be included in node.js broadcast.

Hope this helps. There is no clean way to do this without using other technologies (node.js / web socket / SSE etc). Much of it depends up on the configuration your clients will be using as well.

Comment: Would socket.io seem suitable, in terms of working with AngularJS and Laravel?

Comment: socket.io should be alright. You will still need to notify the node server (which hosts socket.io) from laravel (either direct http or using redis etc) that there is a message need broadcasting.